# Writing a simple sorting algorithm in c++, along with a pseudo code version

Tags: c++, sorting, pseudocode

I'm trying to write a sorting algorithm of sorts in C++, and then write it up in pseudo code after which, now writing it in pseudo is not too bad, however getting it down in my head is turning into a struggle, so the question I pose to you guys:

I'm looking to create an algorithm that takes an unsorted array,along with two integers(Lets say B AND C) and outputs TRUE, if A contains an element which is both greater than B and less than C, otherwise it returns FALSE.

```
For J <-- 1 to Length[A]
       Count <-- j+1
              while Count =< Length[A]
```

This is my start for pseudo code, seeing as that seemed like the logical thing to start with, then implement it in c++, However I found myself going round in circles creating loops, and not making much progress. Hope everything I've said makes sense and someone can put it all together to create some form of solution. thanks.

Comment: Would `std::sort` work for you?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with sorting. First you say you want to sort an array, but then you say that you simply want to find out if there's elements greater than B and less than C.

Comment: Im sorry it was not clear, the code above is not suppose to be c++, its a kind of pseudo code, hence the '<--', I need to compare to intergers to elements within an array, TRUE if the array contains an element which is both greater than B and less than C, FALSE otherwise,

Comment: Again, needs to be written in this style of pseudo code

Comment: Probably not what you want, but here's an example pseudo-code to do what you requested: http://ideone.com/YBIyQf

Comment: If you're even remotely interested in an excellent text on algorithms (and special attention to sorting algorithms) in C++, you'll be hard-pressed to find a better text than Sedgewicks, [Algorithms in C++, Parts 1-4](http://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-Parts-1-4-Fundamentals-Structure/dp/0201350882). It is an excellent reference to keep in your library.

Answer (score 1):

From what I recall from Steve McConnell's *Code Complete*, your pseudocode should ideally look a lot more like English than it does.  You're jumping too quickly to implementation in my humble opinion.

What about this:

```
for each element in array
    check to see if element is between B and C
    if element is between B and C
        return TRUE
    else
        continue loop
next

return FALSE
```

That's what I gather from your statement:

> I'm looking to create an algorithm that takes an unsorted array,along
>   with two integers(Lets say B AND C) and outputs TRUE, if A contains an
>   element which is both greater than B and less than C, otherwise it
>   returns FALSE.

Comment: That's somewhat similar yes, Unfortunately we've been taught this odd style of pseudo code, thus I can't seem to find any information to help me out on it, other than resources handed out, which is far from enough really

Comment: Oh OK. I'm not familiar with that methodology for pseudocode.  In practice, though, I'd argue that if you're having issues with understanding the pseudocode, it's not really doing its job.  It should *help* you clarify your logic, not hide it further.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with a function to check the condition you care about: given a number, does it fall within a specified range:

```
boolean function in_range(A, B, C) {
    return (A > B) and (A < C);
}
```

From there, it becomes a simple matter of scanning through the array and calling the function, passing each element of the array as `A` (and the `B` and `C` that were supplied as `B` and `C`). If the function returns `true` at any point, you can stop scanning and the outer function returns true as well (for what it's worth, C++11 provides `std::any_of` for this kind of situation).

Comment: Thanks, both of these posts help me write the code in c++, I suppose from there I can write it in the pseudo code style we've been shown without too much trouble. thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

You are just searching for an x inside the array that matches the criteria x > B && x < C. A linear search would do - if you are going do the search only once. If search has to be done multiple times (anything more than log (size of array)) then it makes sense to sort first and then do a binary search.

```
bool InRangeSearch(low, high)
{
  index = upper_bound(array, low);
  if(index==-1)
    return false;

  index2 = lower_bound(array, high);
  if(index2==-1)
    return true;

  return ((index2-1)>index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
Quicksort(A as array, low as int, high as int)
    if (low < high)
        pivot_location = Partition(A,low,high)
    Quicksort(A,low, pivot_location - 1)
    Quicksort(A, pivot_location + 1, high)

Partition(A as array, low as int, high as int)
     pivot = A[low]
     leftwall = low

     for i = low + 1 to high
         if (A[i] < pivot) then
             leftwall = leftwall + 1
             swap(A[i], A[leftwall])

     swap(A[low],A[leftwall])

    return (leftwall)
```

Program Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void quickSort( int[], int, int);
int partition( int[], int, int);


int  main() 
{
    int a[] = { 7, 12, 1, -2, 0, 15, 4, 11, 9};

    int i;
    printf("\n\nUnsorted array is:  ");
    for(i = 0; i < 9; ++i)      printf(" %d ", a[i]);

    quickSort( a, 0, 8);

    printf("\n\nSorted array is:  ");
    for(i = 0; i < 9; ++i)      printf(" %d ", a[i]);

    printf("\n\n " );
    return 0;

}



void quickSort( int a[], int l, int r)
{
   int j;

   if( l < r ) 
   {

        j = partition( a, l, r);
       quickSort( a, l, j-1);
       quickSort( a, j+1, r);
   }

}



int partition( int a[], int l, int r) {
   int pivot, i, j, t;
   pivot = a[l];
   i = l; j = r+1;

   while( 1)
   {
    do ++i; while( a[i] <= pivot && i <= r );
    do --j; while( a[j] > pivot );
    if( i >= j ) break;
    t = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = t;
   }
   t = a[l]; a[l] = a[j]; a[j] = t;
   return j;
}
```